C++ - Trying to understand virtual functions, virtual tables and why does this program seg faults

The following program causes a seg fault.
From printing I saw that no Dtor is called before the crash.

In gdb I saw that each Y object contains a pointer to its vtable.
So when trying to delete an object the program will search for the Dtor in Y's vtable.

However, we're using an X pointer to a Y object -

So my theory is that the program tries to access the entry in Y's vtable corresponding with X's Dtor, because (and this is what I'm trying to get a confirmation for) it calculates the offset (from the beginning of the vtable) using the name of the function ('~X' cause the pointer is of type X), and this makes it try to access an invalid address.

So the question is - how is the offset from the start of the vtable calculated? is it really from the name of the func?

Please let me know what you guys think and if I'm talking complete nonsense please correct me XD

Thnx A bunch :)


class X
{
public:
    virtual ~X() {}
    
private:
    double m_a;
};

class Y: public X
{
private:
    int m_b;
};

int main()
{
    X *xp = new Y[5];
    delete[] xp;

    return 0;
}

And 2 more things I'm trying to figure out:

Why when I change m_b's type to double (or any other 8 bytes long types) the program doesn't crash?

Why when I make X's Dtor non-virtual also the program doesn't crash?

p.s - I'm using C++ 98 with g++ compiler.



In this line  X *xp = new Y[5]; xp  is not an pointer to an array but a pointer to the base class of the first element of the newly created array. So delete[] xp can't delete an array through the xp pointer..

dynamic type erasure and  array allocation\deletion aren't compatible, it's ub. Using a pointer at X you can destroy either one instance of Y or array of X. There might be implementations where it can work, but not necessarily.

@Swift-FridayPie dont know why is this UB, but in msvc version all this work correct

You can use a X* to refer to a Y.  But you cannot use a X* to refer an array of Y.  An array of something is an array; an array of something is not a something.

Why when I change m_b's type to double (or any other 8 bytes long types) the program doesn't crash? -- Why when I make X's Dtor non-virtual also the program doesn't crash? -- To be honest, are you going to spend a lot of time trying to figure out undefined behavior?   Undefined behavior is just that -- undefined.  What if another version of the compiler, or different compiler settings, or something else, causes different behavior?

Lets try to see how the object in the new are stored, ill think 32 bit pointers/ints, X,Y are pointers to respective vtable (an implementation detail you can't assume is right), a for m_a and b for m_b, one letter per byte. Only 3 elements shown from the allocation.
Y000aaaaaaaabbbbY001aaaaaaaabbbbY002aaaaaaaabbbb

how xp sees the world
X000bbbbX001bbbbX002bbbb

When we put them together there is a problem
Y000aaaaaaaabbbbY001aaaaaaaabbbbY002aaaaaaaabbbb
X000bbbbX001bbbbX002bbbb
        ^^^^

so when the destructor is called the first X000, is the virtual from Y, neither does anything. When the 2nd is called X001 is really the last 4 bytes of the double that is used as the virtual address for X's destructor, and that is likely null and you get a segfault.
When changing X to none-virtual destructor, you don't call the vtable so no crash.
Changing b to 8 byte
Y000aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbY001aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
X000bbbbbbbbX001bbbbbbbbX002bbbbbbbb
            ^^^^

This should crash, if not there might be some padding at work here or pointers are 8 bytes.
Y0000000aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbY0000001aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
X0000000bbbbbbbbX0000001bbbbbbbbX0000002bbbbbbbb
                ^^^^^^^^

Using m_b as virtual table pointer which is either null or a random address.

Thank you for the answer. But something still doesn't add up for me: so when the destructor is called the first X000, is the virtual from Y, neither does anything   here you claim that the first call to the Dtor should be just fine, but when I put a print in it I don't see it, meaning the program crashes before that.

@AlonKalif that could be because of some optimizations, do you use -O0?

this is the compilation command: g++ -std=c++98 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -g I think it's -O0 if I don't specify it right?

Seems to be -O0 as default. But I don't think we get further here as different compilers give different results as the matter is undefined behavior.

I think I have an answer. When we use new[] and then use delete[], the objects need to be destroyed in the reverse order of their creation. So maybe I didn't see any print from the Dtor is because the first Dtor attempted to be called was in xp[4], and In that place in memory lies a double. Do you think my explanation is correct?

i think this code must work correct. how minimun it correct generated and work with msvc compiler.
void DbgPrint(const char* fmt, ...);

class X
{
    char m_a[0x18];
public:
    virtual ~X() { 
        DbgPrint("%hs<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this); 
    }

    X() { 
        DbgPrint("%hs<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this); 
    }
    
    void operator delete[](PVOID pv)
    {
        DbgPrint("%hs<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, pv);
        free(pv);
    }

    void* operator new[](size_t s)
    {
        PVOID pv = malloc(s);
        DbgPrint("%hs<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, pv);
        return pv;
    }
};

class Y : public X
{
    char m_b[0x20];
public:
    virtual ~Y() { 
        DbgPrint("%hs<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this); 
    }
    Y() { 
        DbgPrint("%hs<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this); 
    }
};

void test ()
{
    if (X *xp = new Y[2])
    {
        DbgPrint(";;;; xp = %p ;;;;\n", xp);
        delete[] xp;
    }
}

and it output:
X::operator new[]<00000214750FEC70>
X::X<00000214750FEC78>
Y::Y<00000214750FEC78>
X::X<00000214750FECB8>
Y::Y<00000214750FECB8>
;;;; xp = 00000214750FEC78 ;;;;
Y::~Y<00000214750FECB8>
X::~X<00000214750FECB8>
Y::~Y<00000214750FEC78>
X::~X<00000214750FEC78>
X::operator delete[]<00000214750FEC70>

( operator new[]/delete[] i add only for dbgprint memory allocation values, code will be correct work without it also)
in general this code first allocate memory for header + N objects:
size_t cbHeader = (sizeof(size_t) + alignof(Y) - 1) & ~(alignof(Y) - 1);

void* pv = malloc(cbHeader + N * sizeof(Y));

in begin of this memory write count of objects
*(size_t*)pv = N;

and then call
void `vector constructor iterator'(
    void *pv, 
    size_t s, 
    size_t n, 
    void * (*fn)(void *));

`vector constructor iterator'((char*)pv + cbHeader, sizeof(Y), N, &Y::Y);

and return xp = (char*)pv + cbHeader;
the delete[] xp; is virtual call. so called via pointer to virtual table in xp
as result called is
virtual void * Y::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int);

function in class Y, despite xp declared as X*
this
Y::`vector deleting destructor'

internally call
  void `vector destructor iterator'(
    void *pv, 
    size_t s, 
    size_t n, 
    void * (*fn)(void *));

    `vector destructor iterator'(xp, sizeof(Y), *(size_t*)((char*)xp - cbHeader), &Y::Y)

and finally free memory block.
so if your code crash, it probable error compiler implementation

I tried it on Godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/b6WEv73bE and I only get the X destructors. Newest GCC, in MSVC I get both though(but not using the same flags as GCC).

@Surt key point is how delete[] xp; is translated. in your example this is static (compile time) call and in my case this is virtual call via vtable in xp. this make different

@Surt https://godbolt.org/z/sh3cabGW8 how you can view in case msvc output is correct

I will have to point you at the already answered answer, deleting one type as another type is UB.

@Surt possible say that this code is not portable, as gcc/clang not handle it corect. however msvc(cl) implementation generate correct code for this. because delete[] xp called via pointer in vtable - called actual type deleter Y::vector deleting destructor'

If you add the global delete overload, you should see free sizeof X * elements from a X* not get a virtual size of Y.

@Surt at first new/delete overload here not playing any role. I use it only for debug output. You can remove it and result in msvc  still will be correct. And delete take pointer only to memory block here. Not it size. In any case look at the msvc again - it correct handle such construction


The following program causes a seg fault.

Why the program causes a seg fault is that creating new Y[5], allocating an array of 5 Y objects, to store in a pointer of type X* is Y objects. And then call delete[]. Since X has a virtual destructor, the runtime tries to call the destructor for each X object in the array. But it doesn’t correctly handle the destructors for the Y objects, which causes seg fault.
What you can try to use std::vector to store derived objects Y in a base class pointer X*.
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> objects;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Y>());
}

